# Convergence speed of discrete approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation-theory, linear-regression

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239838/goodness-of-discrete-approximation) I asked the question about approximating the function $g(x) := \mathbb{E}(f(x,Y))$, where $x \in R$ and $Y$ is a random variable. If you follow the link you will see that $g(x)$ can be approximated by finite sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x,\mu_i)$ with any precision we desire.

My question: whats is the speed of the convergence? Can we deduce how large $n$ should be to make error $\leq \epsilon$

Feel free to impose any reasonable conditions on $f$ and distribution of $Y$

Comment: Are you looking for something on the lines on [concentration inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality)?

Comment: @sudeep5221, I am looking for anything that could tell me how good my discrete approximation is